# Node.js module is looking for node-modules instead of node_modules

Tags: node.js, api, react-native, npm, node-modules

I have the following based on instructions from [here](https://github.com/Wobow/pubg_api/):

```
const Pubgapi = require('pubg-api');
const apiInstance = new Pubgapi('api-key');
```

For some reason when I run it, the console says unable to resolve path but it's looking for a node-modules which I don't have. This is an API wrapper that I am trying to use by the way. What could cause it to give me this error?

I did an npm install as the instructions said and nothing else before the statements above.

Error message:

```
Unable to resolve ../node-modules/pubg-api" from ".//components/Main.js`: The module `../node-modules/pubg-api` could not be found"
```

I have checked the node_modules folder. It is indeed pubg-api, not pubg_api. Requiring pubg_api gives me this error.

[image]

Comment: What is it looking for exactly? Can you give us the error message?

Comment: Make sure you are running npm install in correct directory..It will create a node_module folder automatically

Comment: Added error message also that is not an issue it already created everything just the require is looking for - instead of _

Comment: It looks like the file `./components/Main.js` contains `require('../node-modules/pubg-api')`, or an equivalent `import` statement. Did you write `Main.js`? If so, change it to `node_modules`. (Or else just `require('pubg_api')`.) And note also that the module you're loading is `pubg_api`, not `pubg-api`.

Comment: Did you try changing `Main.js` like I said? Did you try any of the suggestions in the "Edit2" error message or follow the link?

Comment: Yes David I did as for the solution given by the simulator I did that but when I tried to npm install it back it just freezes halfway through every time so I gave up on that and am on my backup files now.

Answer (score 0):

This error is probably related to the HTTPS library that the library you are trying to install [depends on](https://github.com/Wobow/pubg_api/blob/6f6cba3badd1c8a976d6a10e8cabab89cd375b08/package.json#L23). Node.js libraries are not compatible with react-native since it is not working on a Node.js platform.

To overcome this issue you can try to use [react-native-http](https://github.com/tradle/react-native-http) library, but I did not try to use it before, so I'm not sure if it's going to work or not.